# javascript strip words from url

Tags: javascript, regex

i got a little book marklet

```
javascript:window.location='http://alexa.com/siteinfo/'+window.location.host;
```

when clicked it takes you to `alexa.com/siteinfo/www.thesiteyouwereon.com`

i dont know a lot about js regex..is there a way to get rid of the `www.` from the begining of the site. so i can get `alexa.com/siteinfo/nowwwsite.com`

thanks for the help..sorry if this was stupid q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove www:
`String(window.location.host).replace(/^www\./,'')`

Remove http, https, and www:
`String(window.location.host).replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/,'')`

Regex is really worth learning. Really.

Explanation of regex:

- `^` means at the start of the input (either line, or string depending on the `m` modifier). And `$` means at the end.
- `?` means optional, or if used with `*` or `+` means least
- `*` means zero or more
- `+` means one or more
- `.` means any character, so if you want jut a dot, then use `\.` as it must be escaped.
- `[a-z0-9_]` means any a to z, 0 to 9, and a underscore character.
- `[^a-z]` means anything that is not a to z character.
- `()` surrounds a group
- `$1` references the first group

Comment: [`window.location.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/host) will never have `http`/`https`, that's [`window.location.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/protocol). But `window.location.host` might contain the port number, so you should use [`window.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname) instead.